# Getting broken image on mobile

Tags: html, css, image, media-queries, responsive

I currently have a responsive image on my website and when I view it on a mobile browser, I get a broken icon [image] (NOTE: viewing on PC in responsive view works!)

HTML:

```
    <div id="headerwrap">
    <header class="clearfix">
        <div class="container">
            <h1><img src="assets/img/headerImage.png"></img></h1>
            <p>Welcome to the site!</p>
        </div><!-- /container -->
    </header>       
</div><!-- /headerwrap -->
```

CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 979px) {
#headerwrap {
    margin-top: -120px;
    padding-top:140px;
    }

#headerwrap h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 60px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    }


#headerwrap p {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 30px;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 30.6em) { 

.cbp-qtrotator {
    font-size: 70%;
}

.cbp-qtrotator img {
    width: 80px;
}

}
```

When I load the page, the image LOADS then after a second or two switches to the broken link. This happens every-time the page is refreshed.

Troubleshooting done so far:

- Made sure `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` was present
- Took the `<img>` tag out of the `<h1>` element, still didn't show up. Also moved the image outside of the `headerwrap`, still nothing
- Removed most of the CSS regarding `@media (max-width..)`
- Opened the page on PC, and changed the resolution to the same as my phone, result was that the image DID show up
- Viewed the page in Desktop View on my phone, didn't show up.

  If anyone can think of something I'm missing here, I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: Try to correct the `img` tag. `img` tag has no closing tag.

Comment: Do you have any javascript running that may be altering the src attribute of the image? Check the image's "src" attribute when you see the broken icon to see if it matches the destination of your image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @hellojebus the `src` of the image was being changed by a script I had running in the background.

Rather than the img src showing up as:

```
<h1><img src="assets/img/headerImage.png"></img></h1>
```

It loaded as:

```
<h1><img src="assets/img/headerImage@2x.png"></img></h1>
```

Resulting in a 404

Thanks again @hellojebus

Comment: You got it buddy.